# How do I open NEF files with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, camera-raw

Is it possible to open NEFs (Nikon's RAW format) with GIMP? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [UFRaw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/index.html). You didn't specify the OS in your question but it's available for Windows, Linux and Mac